# Unix commands to execute git

Tags: linux, bash, git, unix, xargs

Hey everyone how can I get this command to work. and not

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name .git -type d | rev | cut -c 6- | rev | xargs -I {} git -C {} reset --hard origin/master
```

Context: I have an automation toon in a VE, that contains multiple repos. All relevant to the automation of information. I have an if statement to git clone if the files dont exist. Although in the case that the files do exist I want to reset to master and pull before running the automation commands.

So this command works the former does not.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name .git -type d | rev | cut -c 6- | rev | xargs -I {} git -C {} pull origin master
```

Comment: How is the latter any different than `git -C .git pull origin master`?

Comment: I believe --xargs doesn't like the -- in (--hard)

Comment: What are you even trying to do here? `find -maxdepth 1 .git` means you're already in a work tree, so just plain `git` is the same as what `find` would turn  `git -C {}`  into.

Comment: That was a typo, maxdept 2 should be in its place. The goal was to reseat each git repository within a directory to master.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution around the problem. Because the (--) in --hard was confusing xargs. I needed to reset the branch because of merge conflicts once I pulled the latest changes. I got around to this by

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name .git -type d | rev | cut -c 6- | rev | xargs -I {} git -C {} pull stash
find . -maxdepth 2 -name .git -type d | rev | cut -c 6- | rev | xargs -I {} git -C {} stash clear
find . -maxdepth 2 -name .git -type d | rev | cut -c 6- | rev | xargs -I {} git -C {} pull origin master
```

Comment: Note that this code is generally buggy if you can't guarantee that your directory names are sane. If someone does a `mkdir -p $'./\n..\n/.git'` for example, you'll have a line with just `..` in its output; substitute whatever other value someone might want to put in that place. It's safer to use either `find -exec` or `find -print0` to pass values out, since all possible C strings will work verbatim.

Comment: As a concrete example: `find . -maxdepth 2 -name .git -type d -exec sh -c 'for dir; do (cd "${dir%/*}" && git pull stash && git stash clear && git pull origin master); done' _ {} +` -- no need for all the `rev | cut | rev` mess, and if the number of directories is small enough to fit in `ARG_MAX`, starts only one shell with the entire list of subdirectories passed on its command line.